# Need help with this problem on the applications of the Hahn-Banach Theorem for normed spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $p$ is a defined on a vector space $X$ and satisfies the properties

$p(x+y) \le p(x) + p(y)$ and $p(\alpha x) = |\alpha|p(x)$,

how do I show that for any $x_0 \in X$ there exists some linear functional $\bar f$ such that $\bar f(x_0) = p(x_0)$ and $|\bar f(x)| \le p(x)$ for all $x \in X$?

Comment: Start with $ p(x)\geq 0$ because $ p(2y)\leq p(x+y)+p(-x+y)\leq (p(x)+p(y))+(p(-x)+p(y))=2p(x)+p(2y).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the one dimensional subspace $W$ spanned by $x_0$ and define $f:W\to k$ by
$$
f(\alpha x_0) = \alpha p(x_0)
$$
This is a well-defined linear functional that satisfies $|f(x)| \leq p(x)$ for all $x\in W$. Now simply apply Hahn-Banach to get $\overline{f}$ defined on the whole space.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain how $|f(x)| \le p(x)$? I've noted from the comment to the question above that $p(x) \ge 0$, so does it follow directly from this that: $|f(x)| = |\alpha | p(x_0) = p(\alpha x_0) = p(x)$? Only problem, I'm not getting the inequality.

Comment: Any element of $W$ is of the form $\alpha x_0$ for some $\alpha \in k$, so since $p(x_0) \geq 0$, $$|f(x)| = |\alpha p(x_0)| = |\alpha|p(x_0) = p(\alpha x_0) = p(x)$$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you've commented. As I said above, this isn't an inequality. Do we know $p(x)$ is real so we can write $p(x) = |p(x)|$? Otherwise, how are we able to say this last equality holds if $p(x)$ is complex?

Comment: In your defining property of $p$ there is an inequality, which implicitly means that $p$ is real-valued.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.